# Class is move constructible and assignable even if I implement a copy assignment operator

Tags: c++

In `The C++ Programming Language 4th edition`, the author says that

> • If the programmer declares a copy operation, a move operation, or a destructor for a class, no copy operation, move operation, or destructor is generated for that class.
>
> • If the programmer declares any constructor for a class, the default constructor is not generated for that class.

So I was trying to see that in action, so I implemented an example that is also in the book, a simple class that has an `std::vector` member, an implementation of a default constructor and a copy assignment operator.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

class tic {
public:
    tic() : p(9) {}

    tic &operator=(const tic& t) {
        for(int i = 0; i < t.p.size(); i++)
            p.at(i) = t.p.at(i);
        return *this;
    }

private:
    std::vector<int> p;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << std::is_move_constructible<tic>::value <<  
          ' ' << std::is_move_assignable<tic>::value;
    return 0;
}
```

And I can't understand why is the output 
`true true`? I've tried to implement a constructor other than the default, and I wasn't able to use the generated default constructor, as specified, but in the case of copy assignment, I've implemented it and the class is still move-assignable and constructible.

Comment: A copy-constructor  matches a move request  . If a class has both copy and move constructors then overload resolution will select the latter for a move request.

Comment: `std::is_move_constructible` is not a has_move_constructor, but answer the question "can it be constructed from r-value".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::is_move_assignable` only checks if the target class can be assigned from an rvalue of itself, which it can. A const lvalue reference can bind to rvalues, so as long as `declval<tic&>() = declval<tic&&>()` compiles, `std::is_move_assignable` returns true.

To be more explicit, you can set the move-assignment operator as `deleted`. That way it participates in overload resolution and the move assignable check will fail.

Comment: I didn't fully understand, sadly, but I can infer that this doesn't mean that move semantics are implemented by default, I still have to implement them or it will just copy, am I right?

Comment: @user442029 Yes, creating a copy-assignment operator will inhibit the creation of the default move-assignment operator. You'll have to implement it yourself. Or you can follow the [rule of zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) and  let the compiler create the copy/move assignment operator itself. Your `std::vector` data member already has copy and move semantics so you don't actually need to implement that operator in your class. Just let the compiler write it and everything will be fine.

Comment: Yes, this chapter was talking about the rule of zero and I knew what to do, it was just strange to think that the compiler created the move semantics even though I violated the rule. Thank you.

Comment: @user442029 If I have `tic foo;` and I do `foo = tic()`, this will call the operator you defined in your example, the copy-assignment operator. The argument to that operator `( const tic & )` can still take an rvalue such as `tic()`. There are no move-semantics in this code, the compiler will still make a copy the same as if you had done `tic bar; foo = bar;`.